# Plugin update warning

Tags: plugins, updates

Is it possible to show a warning message for a certain plugin update? For example from version 0.3 or lower to 0.4 or higher?

EDIT:
I need something like upgrade notice (wich doesn't work correctly at the moment) i found a interesting article [here](https://andidittrich.de/2015/05/howto-upgrade-notice-for-wordpress-plugins.html).

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you want and what you have tried so far?

Comment: before update, after update, during update? please be more descriptive

Comment: it is for critical updates where the users have to modify some theme components needed for the plugin. So the warning should be definitely before the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible unless you plan in advance in your plugin for such a possibility. And even if it was somehow possible you are still not likely to have any user read the message and actually understand it.

A more realistic approach is to do a two steps upgrade, in the first vesion of your plugin to maintain appropriate backward compatibility and only later you remove it from your code, giving both you the option to give proper notification, and the user time to adjust whatever he needs.

Comment: Whats about the upgrade notice in the readme.txt?

Comment: In theory you can parse the change log or the readme.txt file but this assumes you have written the code to handle that in the current version. If you don't have it then it doesn't matter where the information is as your code is not ready to parse it. As for assuming users read anything, that is very wrong assumption. It is likely that 50% of your users do not speak english at all, or do not understand technical terms. The best thing is just to avoid breaking changes or at least be mentaly prepared to people being upset

Comment: The parsing thing would be the goto solution. Of course i try to avoid breaking changes but as the plugin evolves there are points where the code has to change. The whole thing is a bit more complicated in my case because the plugin works with code pieces provided by the theme.

Comment: The specific problem in my case was that the plugin passes 2 parameters to a hook (module id and module type). But in the newer version it passes only the module object as single parameter

Comment: enter rant mode.... and this is why people hate to upgrade, you can just never know when a plugin or theme will have a major change that will break other things. /end rant. You set up an API, the API is a long term commitment on you side. Look at wordpress core, even with depercation notice there was no API being actually deprecated for almost 4 year. If core can do it with so much more APIs to maintain, it is not impossible. Maybe you should be more creative at how to avoid the problem in the first place

Comment: It would be avoidable like ($module->id, $module->type, $module) instead of the new ($module) but that would have been a pretty dirty solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Being that this is over 2 years old and all, I imagine, at least I would hope, that by now the updates have rolled out and were either handled without issues or caused a bunch of breakages that then had to be fixed. For anyone reading this, I think it does a perfect job at pointing out what Mark Kaplun eluded to in the comments of the accepted answer. There are an absurd number of plugins out there for WordPress, and it is actually very common even in very popular plugins, for a developer or whole development team to just go about doing something in so much the wrong way. This is why updates so often break sites. If you're listening, please stop it, LOL.

In this case, as revealed in the comments, the developer has a plugin that takes direct function calls from the theme, presumably not a unique theme that he has any control over and can push updates to, hence the predicament. There is a very obvious and simple solution to the problem that would have solved it cleanly, and avoided any breakages for all future versions regardless of whether or not the functions in the theme were ever updated. Not to mention, it's also very bad practice to tell your users that they have to go through ever piece of their code in their theme where they called your function and change it now, because you couldn't be bothered to handle the function update correctly. Issuing a notice to warn users about this "required" change to all function calls, is the completely wrong approach to solving this problem, however the developer couldn't see that. He only knew how he wanted to try to solve it, and so he asked only the question that mattered to him, and it was also the wrong question.

Assuming the code goes something like this:

```
// Plugin functions
...
// version 0.3
public function get_module($id, $name){
        // code that only handles $id and $name parameters
}

// version 0.4
public function get_module($module){
        // code that only handles $module as an object
}

// Theme code
$modulator = new Plugin_Class();
$module = $modulator->get_module(21, 'My Module');
```

The real problem has nothing to do with notices or warnings to display to the user. As soon as version 0.4 pushes out, presumably everyone who's ever used this plugin will see there site break on a totally avoidable fatal error because the plugin code is now expecting an object and they are passing it an id and a name, potentially in a lot of places throughout their code, that they now have to track down and deal with because the developer didn't bother handling it correctly. The real solution should look like this:

```
// Plugin functions
...
// version 0.4
public function get_module_by_id($id){
        //code to retrieve and return the module object by its ID
        return $module
}
public function get_module($module){
        if(!is_object($module)){
                $module = $this->get_module_by_id($module);
        }
        // now you have your module object that you need, the rest of the code should be exactly as it would have for version 0.4
}

// Theme code
$modulator = new Plugin_Class();
$module = $modulator->get_module(21, 'My Module');
// Still works in every future version of the plugin, until you decide to break it another way with an update of course.
```

As I said before, there's a time and place for notices/warnings to the user, but this isn't one of them. Think before you code, your users will appreciate it even if they don't know that they do. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. I think at that time i digged into how to update plugins in general. Solutions like yours should always be the goto solution … handling updates and backward compatibility gracefully should be crucial in any plugin … so totally agree with you and Mark Kapluns rant :D

Comment: Thanks, I hope you didn't take any offense to any of it. It's not really an issue that's unique to any particular dev, we've all done it, I know I have. I'm sure that my code examples were ultra simplistic compared to what you were actually working on, but the principle is there. Sometimes we just think about how we think we can solve it, and then seek answers to how to do that specific thing, then before you know it a year later you're refactoring a whole lot more code to make up for taking the wrong path early on. I just thought there was a valuable lesson in there that was worth noting. :-)

Comment: Yeah your example is a dream :P … not only can you solve the backwards compatibility pretty simple but also you make the function more convenient because you can use it in the new version with id and object. If it would be just that easy in real life all the time :D

Answer (score 0):

You can access the full list of available plugin updates with [`get_plugin_updates()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_updates/) function.

You just need to verify if your plugin is there, then check with the versions, and the best way to output a warning in the admin endpoint is with `admin_notices` hook

Specify your plugin name in the `$requested_name` variable (line:4)

```
add_action('admin_init', function() { 

    // Specify here the plugin name
    $requested_name = 'AJAX File Upload';

    function se_plugin_has_update( $name ) {

        if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugin_updates' ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/update.php';
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
        }

        $list = get_plugin_updates();
        $data = array();

        foreach( $list as $i => $item ) {   
            if( strtolower( $name ) == strtolower( $item->Name ) ) {
                $data = $list[$i];
            }
        }

        if( ! empty( $data ) ) {

            $data = array(
                'name' => $data->Name,
                'version' => $data->Version,
                'new_version' => $data->update->new_version,
                'url' => $data->update->url,
                'package' => $data->update->package
            );

        } else {
            $data = array();
        }

        return $data;

    }

    $update_data = se_plugin_has_update( $requested_name );

    // var_dump( $update_data ) or print_r( $update_data ) for debugging

    if( ! empty( $update_data ) ) { // has update avail

        // You can avoid for specific versions (current: $update_data['version'] and latest: $update_data['new_version'])

        $GLOBALS['se_plugin_has_update_data'] = $update_data;

        add_action( 'admin_notices', function() {

            global $se_plugin_has_update_data;
            $update_data = $se_plugin_has_update_data;

            ?>

                <div id="updated" class="error notice is-dismissible">
                    <p><?php echo sprintf(
                        "\"%s\" plugin has updates available. You are running v. %s while the latest version is %s",
                        $update_data['name'],
                        $update_data['version'],
                        $update_data['new_version']
                    ); ?></p>
                </div>

            <?php
        });

    }

});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Seems usefull but not in my case ... i want a warning for critical updates where the user is notified about changes he have to made in his theme files. But in previous versions i do not really now if there are critical updates in the next version. Only way would be to work 2 versions ahead and that seems not very elegant.